# Why does this leak memory?

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have a function that, when called, takes a `struct Pieces*` field from a `struct Torrent` and initializes it according to the information contained in a char array.

Here is what the function call looks like (metadata.c:230):

```
get_pieces(t.pieces, &t.num_pieces, data);
```

In the `get_pieces()` function, I initialize `t.pieces`, like so (metadata.c:65):

```
pieces = calloc(*num_pieces, sizeof(struct Piece));
```

However, when I run valgrind, it says:

```
==8701== 76,776 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 634 of 634
==8701==    at 0x4C28349: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)
==8701==    by 0x4025A4: get_pieces (metadata.c:65)
==8701==    by 0x402CDB: init_torrent (metadata.c:230)
==8701==    by 0x404018: start_torrent (torrent.c:35)
==8701==    by 0x40232E: main (main.c:17)
```

even though a pointer, `t->pieces`, is still available when my program terminates and can be free'd. Why does this leak memory?

The full source code is available at https://github.com/robertseaton/slug.

Comment: where and how do you free the allocated memory?

Comment: he does not free it, but there is still a reference to it (or at least he thinks there is a reference to it...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This leaks memory because your `get_pieces` function is passing in a pointer to Pieces:

```
void get_pieces (struct Piece* pieces, ...
```

You then allocate memory to `pieces` inside of this method.  When it returns, that allocated memory is no longer accessible by anything.

This is because your pointer is passed by value - reassigning the pointer does not change the calling function's copy.  In order to affect that calling function, you'd have to pass a pointer to the pointer, so you can assign the original copy correctly:

```
void get_pieces (struct Piece** pieces, ...
     // ...
      *pieces = malloc(...
```

And, at the call site, pass in the address to the pointer.

Answer (score 8):

You have

```
void get_pieces (struct Piece* pieces, uint64_t* num_pieces, char* data)
{
    /* ... */
    pieces = malloc(sizeof(struct Piece) * *num_pieces);
}
```

After the function is done, the object passed by the caller as the first argument is unchanged, so **the result of `malloc` is lost**. Therefore I don't see how you can free `pieces`.

#### EDIT

As user user786653 observes in the comments, you need to change your function:

```
void get_pieces(struct Piece **pieces...)
{
    /* ... */
    *pieces = malloc(sizeof(struct Piece) * num_pieces);
}
```

Comment: +1 I was writing an answer with the same thing. OP should change it to something like `struct Piece** pieces` and `*pieces = malloc(....`

Comment: @user786653 I think that's what the OP should do.

Answer (score 0):

In the call

```
get_pieces(t.pieces, &t.num_pieces, data)
```

you are passing the pointer t.pieces by value, so it is copied for use in the function. Since you assign to it inside the function but not outside, and these are now two different pointers, the outer pointer is never assigned. The pointer inside the function is destroyed via stack unwinding and the allocated memory sits there on the heap, forgotten.

You can fix this by changing the call to

```
get_pieces(&t.pieces, &t.num_pieces, data)
```